# EFS File not accessable after reboot

Tags: reboot, efs

I have encrypted a file with EFS for a user (let us name this "User X").
An application which is running as "User X", is able to access the encrypted file.
It keeps working fine across log off and log in for any user logging through UI log in screen till next reboot.

Upon reboot, the application running as "User X" is not able to access the encrypted file.

But when I login "User X" from the log in screen, it starts working. Meaning once I log in as "User X" and log off and login as any other user and run my application as "User X" it is able to access the encrypted file.

But as per design I don't want the "User X" to login using the UI screen.

Can anyone suggest, why upon reboot the "User X" is not able to access the EFS encrypted file and how do I resolve it, so that my application running as "User X", should be able to access the encrypted file without logging as user X?

Note: I am using Windows Embedded Std. 7.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There's a process named lsass.exe that's responsible for the security part (auth., logon, encryption, etc...)
If I'm not mistaken this process runs only during interactive logons (like console or RDP).
You can try add a small batch that would first launch lsass.exe.

Comment: Thank you EliadTech! It did not work. Actually After reboort, it does not work, till "User X" log in interactively. Once I log in as "User X" and log off and login as any other user and run my application as "User X" it is able to access the encrypted file.

Answer (score 0):

**A decade later & here is a solution that might work for you:**

If you are able to use the command prompt (batch script [.bat]), or you have written your application in any language that allows you to run external exe's, the answer lies in [PSExec.exe](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) & you don't need admin privileges.

I'm not an expert in how Microsoft's EFS is coded or working under the hood but it seems the problem is something to do with the certificate & private key management programs that are run in the background for each user, only upon user sign in. I say programs because no services are started (other than the ones already running) by signing in to the other user (User X) on the PC.

[PSExec](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/psexec) is able to perform a proper sign-in of a user entirely in the background, whereas 'run as user' (or anything of the like) seems to be imitating the user's security token (again, I'm no Windows employee) with something akin to the [LogonUser](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-logonusera) function.

Anyways, here's the code that fixes the issue once & for all (keep in mind that User X is the user who encrypted the files in the first place):

---

Batch Script:

```
cd [PSExec Extracted Directory]
PSExec -accepteula -d -u "User X" -p "P455W0RD" cipher /c "C:\path\to\any\encrypted.file"
```

Once your batch file has run, run your app on behalf of User X. You can make the batch file start at start-up using Windows' built-in [task scheduler](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/datacap/9.1.6?topic=application-configuring-windows-task-scheduler-automatically-run-ruleset).

What happened above:

1. Go to the PSExec directory.
2. Run PSExec with the following options.
3. (-accepteula) Without this PSExec pops up a prompt for agreeing to their software license.
4. (-d) Don't launch an interactive command prompt.
5. (-u & -p) Username & password for the user that originally encrypted the app you want to run & they must also be the user you want to run the app for (User X).
6. (cipher /c [filePath]) Use EFS to check a file on behalf of User X (this is what starts up the certificate & private key programs on the user once PSExec has properly signed-in as User X).

---

C# Script:

```
//Register a process context for PSExec to initialize a real user logon & relevant EFS programs
ProcessStartInfo execution = new ProcessStartInfo
{
    CreateNoWindow = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    FileName = "C:\\path\\to\\PSExec.exe",
    Arguments = "-accepteula -d -u \"User X\" -p \"P455W0RD\" cipher /c \"C:\\path\\to\\any\encrypted.file\""
};

//Run user & EFS initialization
Process.Start(execution).WaitForExit();

//Initialize execution of an encrypted program on behalf of a user
execution.FileName = directory + "\\Test\\Router\\AppController.exe";
execution.UserName = "User X";
execution.Password = new NetworkCredential("", "P455W0RD").SecurePassword;

//Run the specified user's exclusive application
Process.Start(execution);

//Terminate thread
return;
```

Not the most secure in terms of your passwords, but I'm sure after 9 years of this post being up you'll have your means. Hope this helps someone like me or you who bump into this along the way :).